# What will be the column name after joining two tables in SQL with different join columns

Tags: sql, join

Let's say I write the query

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.student.Number
```

There are the same values in column "ID" of table1 and in column "Number" of table2.
How will the column with the joined values be named in the result table?

"ID" or "Number"?

Comment: It may depend on the RDBMS, but every one I've seen will display both -- since the `select *` inherently displays all columns in all referenced tables.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. you can use alias name to name any columns that you select.

Comment: Thanks, I just found out that it will display both by trying it out on a PostRe SQL Account I got from the course.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them. JOIN does not remove common columns - indeed, if you're doing a join on two tables which share a column name, the result will have two columns with that name. (You can disambiguate them using the table name, e.g. `SELECT table1.id FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.x = table2.y)`.)